# group conversation by users mysql select for messages

Tags: mysql, sql

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE `messages` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `from_user_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `to_user_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `seen` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `sent` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `message` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


INSERT INTO `messages` (`id`, `from_user_id`, `to_user_id`, `seen`, `sent`, `message`)
VALUES
    (1,2,1,0,'2013-11-06 11:05:42','Hello!'),
    (2,1,2,0,'2013-11-06 11:05:52','Hello you too!'),
    (3,3,1,0,'2013-11-06 11:06:08','Whats up?'),
    (4,1,3,0,'2013-11-06 11:06:27','Not much');
```

I would put this in sqlfiddle but it is down for me, I cannot access it last 32 hours.

I've searched SO and found several related topics, but with different grouping requirements so I could not apply them to my project.

For the query, I know current user id and target user id, and based on this I want query to return all conversation of these two users ordered by date.

I was thinking something like:

```
SELECT message FROM messages WHERE from_user_id = 1 OR to_user_id = 1 [but where do I limit this query to target user 3?]
```

In other words I want to select:

```
(3,3,1,0,'2013-11-06 11:06:08','Whats up?')
(4,1,3,0,'2013-11-06 11:06:27','Not much')
```

For user 1, conversation with user 3. All of it.

Comment: by target use, did you mean adding AND to)user=3?

Comment: @Madhivanan I didn't explain it well I guess. I'd like to select this: (3,3,1,0,'2013-11-06 11:06:08','Whats up?'),
    (4,1,3,0,'2013-11-06 11:06:27','Not much');

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT message FROM messages 
WHERE 1 in (from_user_id,to_user_id) and 3 in (from_user_id,to_user_id)
```